# How to disable soReusePort in gRPC C# Channel?

Tags: c#, networking, load-testing, grpc, http2

I'm trying to build a load test application for a Grpc server. I would like the channels to open different ports whenever trying to connect to the server with disabling "SoResuePort Channel Option". By using the following code:

```
string Host = "192.168.1.20";
int Port = 7081;  

IEnumerable<ChannelOption> options = new[] { new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.SoReuseport, 0) };
ChannelOne = new Channel(Host, Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure , options);
ChannelTwo = new Channel(Host, Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure , options);

await ChannelOne.ConnectAsync();
await ChannelTwo.ConnectAsync();
```

I expect gRPC to open a new TCP connection per channel, but it's reusing the same TCP connection.

Comment: The server need to open all the port numbers before the client connects.  Since a connection must be unique (Source IP address, Destination IP address, and Port) if a connection already exists from client to server with a port number a failure will occur and then you need to use a different port number.  You code posted doesn't check if a failure occurs before and the next port number if used.  Does you new channel use the same port number of different port number?  I suspect the zero in the call is the port number and each instance you are calling with zero instead of a new port number.

Comment: all instances of channels are connected to the server and each is working properly but all of them connected through one TCP connection. I also checked out the **gRPC-C version**, it seems they check the value to be non-zero to reuse the same TCP connection but in case it's zero it will build a tcp_listener with new freeport.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong.  Each TCP connection is only one connection.  A TCP Listener can have multiple connections with the same port number but the Remote Endpoint must be different.  You need multiple TCP Listeners if you have more than one port number.

Comment: yeah, your right, the server is listening on one IP and Port, What I'm trying to achieve is that each Channel creates a separate unique port number while connecting to the server since I have no access to change the behavior of Channel creation. If I run two instances of the console application, each one is using different port number but on one instance of console application all channels sharing the same connection

Comment: See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/7e8a6488-5d47-4880-8991-7297a055b461/should-we-add-a-second-msdtc-service-for-the-second-instance-in-sql-server-2008r2-cluster?forum=sqldisasterrecovery  The link is using two instances one for each database.  Not sure why you can't use for two instances for one database except each instance has to use a different port number for client.